# Describing the minimizers of this function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following continuous function over $x$, with $a,b>0$:  $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
ax-\sqrt{x} & \text{for }x\leq b^{2}\\
ab\sqrt{x}-b & \text{for }x>b^{2}
\end{cases}$$Note that this function is convex at first, then concave.  Say I'd like to minimize $f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)$, subject to the constraint that $x_1+\cdots+x_n = c>0$.  What does the optimal solution look like as $c$ varies?  Clearly, when $c$ is really small, the optimal solution has us setting all $x_i=c/n$ , and when $c$ is really large, we're going to have one value $x_i \approx c$ with all other values small.  Can anything more precise be said?

Comment: Have you tried Lagragean method?

Comment: Yes, you can show that the solution either consists of setting all $x_i = c/n$, or otherwise, the solution has a single value (say $x_1$) such that $x_1 > b^2$ and with all other values $x_i=(c-x_1)/n$, and the derivatives have to be equal.  Solving for the exact value requires the solution to a quartic :(

Comment: Well that's pretty good analysis, then. Frankly if someone offered that as an answer, with some of the computational detail added, I'd vote for it. Why don't you?

Comment: Glad you think so, @MichaelGrant -- I guess I'll just stick with that.  PS, CVX is awesome.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm serious about writing up your answer. It's not unheard of to write one's own, and perhaps others will benefit from learning your approach.